# Javascript, check if current part object is inside other part object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to loop over an object and check if a certain property is inside any other certain parts of the object. I am trying to see if the first level.parentSearch is inside any of the other firstlevel.filters array (of objects).

So my object looks like this for example :

```
    var currentfilters = [{
    "id": "topics",
    "name": "Topics",
    "filters": [{
        "id": "isSubTopic",
        "label": "isSubTopic",
        "search": "isSubTopic",
        "num": 15
    }]
}, {
    "id": "isSubTopic",
    "name": "isSubTopic",
    "parentSearch": "isSubTopic",
    "filters": [{
        "id": "subtopicFilter",
        "label": "subtopicFilter",
        "search": "subtopicFilter",
        "num": 2
    }, {
        "id": "subtopicFilter1",
        "label": "subtopicFilter1",
        "search": "subtopicFilter1",
        "num": 2
    }]
}, {
    "id": "notSubTopic",
    "name": "notSubTopic",
    "parentSearch": "uniueParentSearch",
    "filters": [{
        "id": "notSubTopic1",
        "label": "notSubTopic1",
        "search": "notSubTopic1",
        "num": 5
    }]
}
];
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to loop over this object and modify it a little bit (if necessary) and return it. What I am trying to do is check the first level if the .parentSearch property is inside any of the other objects .filter array as a .search property. So in this example isSubTopic would be what I am looking for, because it is inside the Topics filters array.

This is my first time trying these kind of problem, so if I am missing anything please let me know. I figured since I want to return a modified object, it would be good to reduce this object and check inside. The part I am struggling with is the bit that checks if my current parentSearch (in the reduce loop) is in any other objects filter array (under the .search property). I have lodash to mess around with so I have tried both `_.find` and `_.has`, but I think I am not approaching this correctly. Any/all input would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I was trying it with : https://jsfiddle.net/0fttkyey/32/

```
function checkIfSubtopic(memo, value, key) {
if(value.parentSearch) {
//check if value.parentSearch is in any of the value.filters
console.log("find?", _.find(currentfilters, value.parentSearch));
if(_.find(currentfilters, value.parentSearch)){
        console.log("is subtopic?");
} else {
    console.log("not sub topic");
}
}
 return memo;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, your `currentfilters` is not the same in the jsfiddle you provide, so it gives no result.

If I understand correctly, what you try to achieve is:

1. **For each** "filter" in `currentfilters` array, check if `parentSearch` member is truthy.
2. If so, **loop** through all *other* filters.
3. For each of these filters, **loop** through its `filters` array member.
4. If the `search` member of one of the objects in this `filters` array is equal to `parentSearch` value, keep the current "filter".

So you have 3 nested loops.

The 2 outer loops iterate over the same `currentfilters` array, except that the 2nd (inner) one skips the filter which `parentSearch` value is being searched for.

As soon as `parentSearch` value is found, break loops 2 and 3 (the 2 inner-most) and go to next item of 1st (outer-most) loop.

Without using lodash and building a new result array (instead of modifying `currentfilters` array in place which may yield unexpected results), you would have for example:

```js
var i = 0,
  j,
  ifiltermax = currentfilters.length,
  currentParentSearch,
  currentFiltersArray,
  k,
  result = [];

for (; i < ifiltermax; i += 1) { // Loop 1.
  currentParentSearch = currentfilters[i].parentSearch;
  if (currentParentSearch) { // If `parentSearch` is truthy.
    loop_j: for (j = 0; j < ifiltermax; j += 1) { // Loop 2.
      if (j != i) { // Skip current filter which `parentSearch` is being searched for.
        currentFiltersArray = currentfilters[j].filters;
        for (k = 0; k < currentFiltersArray.length; k += 1) { // Loop 3.
          if (currentFiltersArray[k].search === currentParentSearch) {
            result.push(currentfilters[i]); // Keep current "filter".
            console.log("Found " + currentParentSearch + " (from item #" + i + ") in item #" + j + ", filter #" + k);
            break loop_j; // Break loops 2 and 3.
          }
        }
        console.log("Did not find " + currentParentSearch + " (from item #" + i + ") in any other filter.");
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fttkyey/71/ (with `currentfilters` from the question above, instead of the one in jsfiddle version 32).